# css não funciona com div adicionada com append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho uma lista e nela adiciono os elementos com o append do jquery , e os elementos da lista não capturam o css do meu arquivo de estilos, simplesmente ignora. Porque?

html:

```
<ul id="list_arquivos"></ul>
```

css:

```
#list_arquivos{
    list-style:none;
}

#list_arquivos li{
    display:inline;
    background-color: #0C94C7;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#list_arquivos").append(
        '<li>' +
                '<div style="border: 1px solid #FAFAFA">' +
                        '<img src="img/file_icons/'+dados.icon+'">' +
                 '</div>' +
                 '<p>'+dados.nome_arquivo+'</p>' +
        '</li>'
 );
```

Simplesmente fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você referenciou a ul 2 vezes `#list_arquivos ul li`

`#list_arquivos li` já basta...

Comment: O problema é que o css não está se aplicando, de jeito nenhum. Somente com itens staticos que eu adiciono direto no html. Os que adiciono interativamente com o jquery usando append, o css simplesmente não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Então amigo, vindo aqui responder a sua pergunta, o que acaba de acontecer é que você usou o id `#list_arquivos` certo? Então certifique que você já tem a list desordenada já declarada. Aí quando você criou no seu código CSS.

```
#list_arquivos ul li{
    display:inline;
    background-color: #0C94C7;
}
```

Certifique que você está declarando a `#list_arquivos` e logo após `ul`. Ou seja, não precisa declarar a lista desordenada 2 vezes, certo?

Como ficaria então?

Exemplo:

```
#list_arquivos li{
    display:inline;
    background-color: #0C94C7;
}
```

Isso porque você criou um id dentro da sua `ul` - então certifique-se 
de usar ou a `ul` ou a `#list-arquivos`.

Bem, eu espero ter ajudado você. Caso tenha alguma dúvida, pode retornar a perguntar novamente que farei o possível para responder.

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar mas a questão não é essa, eu não tinha percebido é que na hora de copiar para cá mandei errado. A questão é que o css simplesmente não se aplica, entendeu? eu posso colocar um padding de 1000px ou uma cor rosa choque que ela vai continuar do mesmo jeito

Comment: editei a pergunta com uma foto de como fica a lista. Fica vertical, e sem nenhuma cor, mesmo colocando inline e background-color e já tentei aplicar outras propriedades e nada

Answer (score 0):

certo eu entendi, veja um pequeno erro que os desenvolvedores comentem é esquecer totalmente de colocar no seu documento html  o script e o link exemplo :

para css usamos:

1- //aqui você irá especificar o seu arquivo em css para que ele possa conectar ao arquivo

2-// só podemos fazer algo com o jquery se caso estiver esse script dentro da tag head do nosso documento html, aqui você pode copiar e colar no seu documento caso não tenha feito isso..

3-//nesse ultimo exemplo é como ele irá se comportar dentro do seu documento html ai você segue essas explicações caso esteja algo errado com suas declarações.

something

- bem mais uma vez espero poder está ajudando na medida do possível ...

att: Rafael Macedo

Answer (score 0):

Brother cheguei no mesmo problema que o seu e acredito ter achado uma solução, vê se faz sentido pra ti.

No caso como o elemento `li` dentro do `list_arquivos` foi criado via javascript acho que o estilo deveria ser feito da mesma maneira, no caso, logo após o `append` teria outra linha tipo assim:

```
$('#lis_arquivos').append('<li>...</li>')
$('#list_arquivos li').css({
      'display': 'inline', 
      'background-color': '#0C94C7'
});
```

Pra mim funcionou certinho, espero ter ajuda.
Qualquer dúvida da uma olhadinha aqui https://poucaslinhas.com.br/manipulacao-de-css-com-jquery/

Até mais!